# Pegar a localização do usuário (Cidade, Estado, País) com o login do facebook?

Tags: android

Como faço para conseguir pegar a cidade, estado e o país do usuário, com um login do facebook?

Tenho o código abaixo:

```
facebook.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile", "user_birthday","user_location");

private void facebookLogin() {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    facebook.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
            GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d("JSON", "" + response.getJSONObject().toString());
                    try {
                        nome = object.optString("first_name");
                        sobrenome = object.optString("last_name");
                        email = object.optString("email");
                        aniversario = object.optString("user_birthday");
                        idFB = object.optString("id");
                        sexo = object.getString("gender");
                        paisLogin = object.getJSONObject("location").getString("country"); //como fazer a query?
                        cidade = object.getJSONObject("location").getString("city"); //como fazer a query?
                        SaveSharedPreferences.setIdFacebook(getContext(),idFB);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields","id,first_name,last_name,email,location,gender");
            graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
            graphRequest.executeAsync();
            AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            handleFacebookAccessToken(credential);
            //handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Isto funcionou pra mim, acrescentando o método getLocationUser, ele busca a localização baseada no id, vindo do nó "location" no Json anterior:

```
private void facebookLogin() {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    //Login com facebook arrumar um lugar melhor e mais organizado..
    facebook.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
            GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d("JSON", "" + response.getJSONObject().toString());
                    try {
                        nome = object.optString("first_name");
                        sobrenome = object.optString("last_name");
                        email = object.optString("email");
                        aniversario = object.optString("user_birthday");
                        idFB = object.optString("id");
                        sexo = object.getString("gender");
                        locationID = object.getJSONObject("location").getString("id");
                        getLocationUser(locationID); <<<<-----
                        SaveSharedPreferences.setIdFacebook(getContext(),idFB);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields","id,first_name,last_name,email,location,gender");
            graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
            graphRequest.executeAsync();
            AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            handleFacebookAccessToken(credential);
            //handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
            // ...
        }
    });
}

private void getLocationUser(String id) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("location", "id");
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            id+"/?fields=location",
            params,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.e("Response 2", response + "");
                    try {
                        paisLogin = (String) response.getJSONObject().getJSONObject("location").get("country");
                        cidade = (String) response.getJSONObject().getJSONObject("location").get("city");
                        UF = (String) response.getJSONObject().getJSONObject("location").get("state");
                        Log.e("Location", paisLogin);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe mais de uma forma de fazer isso. Na [documentação sobre *Location*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/location), mostra alguns exemplos e parâmetros que você precisa usar para resgatar a localização. No Android, pode fazer uma requisição assíncrona usando a classe `GraphRequest` usando GET, que seria `HttpMethod.GET`. Veja abaixo:

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "...?fields=location",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* aqui será exibida o resultado */

            // para resgatar o nome da cidade, basta resgatar o objeto 
            // JSON passando como parâmetro o nome do campo
            String cidade = (String) response.getJSONObject()
                .getJSONObject("location").get("city");
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Veja abaixo a lista de parâmetros que podem ser passadas para receber os valores específicos:

- `city`: Cidade
- `city_id`: Identificação da cidade
- `country`: País
- `country_code`: Código do país
- `latitude`: Latitude
- `located_in`: Localização principal, caso esteja em outro lugar
- `longitude`: Longitude
- `name`: Nome
- `region`: Região
- `region_id`: Identificação da região
- `state`: Estado
- `street`: Rua
- `zip`: Cep

Veja [mais detalhes na documentação](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/location) sobre *Location*.

Comment: Obrigado! Na minha resposta utilizo isso. Minha maior dúvida era como chamar essa nova "chamada". Mas, em todo caso ela não explicita a questão dos parametros, minha resposta os coloca, sem eles, não é possível pegar os objetos, mas, Obrigado novamente!